How to evaluate the gamma function $ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-h^2x^2}\,dx $?
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-h^2x^2}\,dx $$
How can I evaluate this integral? I was thinking about making the  replacement $ u = h^2x^2$ but then I get $du = 2h^2x\, dx$, I am blind after this...

The solution is the Error Function erf(x) with appropriate scaling, is it not?

This is a Gaussian integral. Why are you calling it a gamma function?

This is a Gaussian integral and is well known.

In my math physics textbook, this integration is given under gamma function exercise...

One way to approach the integral is from this note by Keith Conrad: see part 8 for the gamma solution. https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/gaussianintegral.pdf

Did you write your integral in terms of the $u$ that you defined? Then it will be a gamma function value.

I think it would be easiest to consider the $h^2x^2$ part as $(hx)^2$, as letting $u=hx, \,\, \mathrm du =h \, \mathrm dx\rightarrow \mathrm dx=\dfrac{\mathrm du}{h}$, the integral becomes:
$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-h^2x^2}\mathrm dx}\rightarrow \int_0^\infty{\frac{e^{-u^2}}{h}\mathrm du}.$$
The $\frac{1}{h}$ is constant with respect to $u$ and can be pulled out of the integral, and as you may know,
$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-x^2}\mathrm dx}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}.$$
So the original integral becomes:
$$\int_0^\infty{e^{-h^2x^2}\mathrm dx}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2|h|}.$$
You may rightfully question why I have put absolute values around the answer, but there is a reason. If we let $h$ be negative, the sign disappears in the original integral because of the square and, as such, the answer is always positive, but the negative value still exists in the final answer; luckily for us, the absolute value removes this minus sign and corrects it to the value of the original integral. Hope this helps!

Why didn't we get $|h|$ at the starting then?

Because we are squaring the h, we get given the absolute value for free. So technically the original integral should have had the absolute value of h and not h, we just don't write it because it gets done for us. If you consider |h| instead of h then it becomes a lot easier to see where the absolute value appears in the answer.

You are on the right track, picking up from the substitution;
$$I= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-h^2x^2}\,dx $$
$$h^2x^2=t\implies 2h^2x\,dx=\,dt\implies \,dx=\frac{1}{2h^2x}\,dt$$
$$x=\frac{t^{\frac{1}{2}}}{|h|}\implies \,dx=\frac{t^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{2|h|}\,dt$$
$$I= \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t}\frac{t^{\frac{-1}{2}}}{2|h|}\,dt \implies \frac{1}{2|h|}\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{\frac{-1}{2}}e^{-t}\,dt$$
Using the Gamma function here,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-x}x^{n-1}\,dx =
 \Gamma_n\underset{n=\frac{1}{2}}\implies \int_{0}^{\infty}
e^{-x}x^{\frac{-1}{2}}\,dx = \Gamma_{\frac{1}{2}}=\sqrt{\pi}$$
$$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2|h|}$$
In general,
$$\boxed{I(n,h)=\int_0^{\infty} x^ne^{-h^2x^2}dx=\frac{\Gamma_\left({\frac{n+1}{2}}\right)}{2|h|^{n+1}}}$$

Square the integral in variables $x,y$ and as an integral in the real plane and change chart to  polar coordinates.
$$\left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{-h^2 \ x^2}\right)^2 = \int_0^{\infty}\int_0^{\infty} e^{-h^2 x^2+h^2 y^2} \ dx \ dy =\frac{\pi}{2} \ \int_0^{\infty}\ e^{-h^2\ r^2} \ r \ dr$$

Evaluation of
$$I=\int^\infty_0e^{-h^2x^2}dx$$
Recall the standard Gaussian integral over the entire real line is
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}e^{-ax^2}dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}, 
 \ \text{for}  \ a>0$$
Since $e^{-ax^2}$ is even,
$$\int^\infty_0e^{-ax^2}dx=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{a}}$$
In your integral, $a=h^2$. Hence,
$$I=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{h^2}}=\boxed{\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2|h|}}$$
Why absolute values?
Whether $h$ is positive or negative, $h^2$ is always non-negative. However, integral $I$ is always positive since integrand $e^{-h^2x^2}$ is positive for all $x$. With the absolute values, if $h$ were negative the expression $\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2h}$ would yield a negative result which contradicts the positive nature of the integral.

the absolute value follows from the fact that $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|$
